# Composite indexes for columns in joins and where

Tags: database, optimization, indexing

If I have a query:

```
Select *
From tableA
Inner Join tableB ON tableA.bId = tableB.id
Inner Join tableC ON tableA.cId = tableC.id
where
tableA.someColumn = ?
```

Do I get any performance benefit from creating a composite index(bId,cId,someColumn)?

I'm using DB2 Database for this activity.

Comment: What database vendor & product are you using?

Comment: That depends entirely on the DBMS. The execution plan of your DBMS can answer that question in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing joins depends on the join algorithm used by the database. You'll see that in the execution plan.

You will probably need an index on `tableA` that starts with `someColumn` for the `where` clause. Everything else depends on the join algorithm and join order.

You will probably get a more specific answer if you post the execution plan. You can also read the chapter "[The Join Operation](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join)" on my site about sql indexing and try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no indexes now, I'd *guess* that the composite index might be used in one or both inner joins. I doubt that it would be used in the WHERE clause.

But I've been doing this stuff for a long time. Guessing, like hoping, doesn't scale well.

Instead of guessing, you're better off learning how to use [DB2's explain and design advisor utilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100077/562459).  Expect to test things like indexing first on a development computer. Building a three-column index on a 500 million row table that's in production will *not* make you popular.