# Dynamic way of counting number of previous rows in a table that satisfy some condition, over certain columns in the table

Tags: sql, db2

As a specific example say I have a table `T` with columns `customer` and `date` indicating days on which individual customers have made purchases:

```
customer |   date   
----------------------  
       A | 01/01/2013 
       A | 02/01/2013
       A | 07/01/2013
       A | 11/01/2013
       B | 03/01/2013
       B | 08/01/2013
```

I want to add another column that for each pair `(customer, date)` pair `(c, d)`, gives the number of pairs `(c', d')` in `T` such that `c = c'` and `0 <= days(d) - days(d') <= 7`. Below is the table with this extra column:

```
customer |   date     | new_column
----------------------------------  
       A | 01/01/2013 |          1
       A | 02/01/2013 |          2
       A | 07/01/2013 |          3 
       A | 11/01/2013 |          2
       B | 03/01/2013 |          1
       B | 10/01/2013 |          1
```

As a rough idea of the steps I used to solve this problem:

- create a table `T'` with all possible pairs `(c,d)`;
- left join `T` onto `T'`;
- create a new column: `count(date) over (partition by customer order by date asc rows between 6 preceding and 0 following)`;
- omit any rows from this new table where `T.date is null`

However, I don't think this is scalable.

Cheers for any help.

Comment: You can get the information with a query that has a self join.  Why do you need a new column in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some DDL. (You'll get more answers and better answers if you include DDL and sample INSERT statements in your questions.)

```
create table test (
  customer char(1) not null,
  purchase_date date not null,
  primary key (customer, purchase_date)
);

insert into test values
('A', '2013-01-01'),
('A', '2013-01-02'),
('A', '2013-01-07'),
('A', '2013-01-11'),
('B', '2013-01-03'),
('B', '2013-01-10');
```

In standard SQL, you can use something along these lines. It doesn't require creating another table, outer joins, or window functions. It's not clear whether you have a good reason for wanting to create a new table, but it's not necessary to get the right data.  (I renamed the "date" column to avoid a reserved word.)

```
select t1.customer, t1.purchase_date, count(*) new_column
from test t1
inner join test t2 on t1.customer = t2.customer
and t2.purchase_date <= t1.purchase_date and t2.purchase_date > t1.purchase_date - interval '7 day'
group by t1.customer, t1.purchase_date
order by t1.customer, t1.purchase_date;

customer  purchase_date  new_column
--
A         2013-01-01     1
A         2013-01-02     2
A         2013-01-07     3
A         2013-01-11     2
B         2013-01-03     1
B         2013-01-10     1
```

Whether this scales well depends on how well DB2 handles non-equi joins.  [DB2 EXPLAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100077/562459) will guide you. I'd expect an index on "purchase_date" and a restrictive WHERE clause to perform well.