# DB2 SELECT query with subquery taking long time

Tags: database, db2

I have a DB2 SELECT query which takes a very long time to complete. Is there a much simpler way to achieve the same result?

```
Select count(*) 
from leaveprocess,processlog,leave_type, user_master 
where  leaveprocess.process_id = processlog.process_id 
and user_master.user_id = leaveprocess.create_id  
and leaveprocess.leavetype_id = leave_type.serial_no  
and leaveprocess.leave_cust_id=315
and  user_master.user_id!=0 
and user_master.location_id in (2412,2422,2416,2410,2436,2401)  
and user_master.user_id in (
    select employee_id from employee where employee_cust_id=1558 and company_id in (178)
) 
and leaveprocess.leave_id!=0.
```

There are approx 60,000 records of employee, but when I remove country_id check (`company_id in (178)`) then it working very fast and properly.

Are there some suggestions for improving the speed and optimization of my DB2 Query?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the Explanation of your plan (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098814/how-do-i-use-db2-explain) for more details on `EXPLAIN`) or any table/index definitions, it's hard to say for sure.

However, since you said that it's fast without the `company_id` field in the subquery, I'm guessing that you need an index to cover that on the `employee` table. Probably something like `employee_cust_id, company_id, employee_id`.

Also, you don't need to write it as a subquery, you can write it as a `JOIN` (I converted your comma joins to "real" joins):

```sql
SELECT count(*) 
FROM leaveprocess l
JOIN processlog p
  ON l.process_id = p.process_id 

JOIN leave_type lt
  ON l.leavetype_id = lt.serial_no  

JOIN user_master um 
  ON um.user_id = l.create_id  

JOIN employee e
  ON e.employee_id = um.user_id

where l.leave_cust_id = 315
  and um.user_id     <> 0 
  and l.leave_id     <> 0
  and um.location_id in (2412,2422,2416,2410,2436,2401)  

  and e.employee_cust_id=1558 
  and e.company_id in (178)
```

Comment: Just to reiterate, explicit joins are preferred.  They make it easier to see what you are doing.  It's easy to screw up an implicit join; thus turning it into a cross join.  The ANSI SQL Standard calls for explicit joins.

Comment: @bhamby I tried according to your suggestion but nothing is improve . It still taking too long time

Comment: @rawat0157 what did you try? the statement changes? Or the index? It's hard to give some more suggestions without further details (table structures, indexes, row counts, an explain).

Comment: @bhamby I changed the query, used join instead of subquery. And also create the index for employee table on the following columns(employee_id, employee_cust_id, company_id)

Comment: @bhamby Employee table have 95 columns and more than 2,00,000 records. there are also many indexes basis on different columns on employee table

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using the advice mentioned in the above post, but I'm confused why you are using e.company_id in (178) .  The IN operator is typically used to specify multiple values.  You are only looking for e.company_id 178, so perhaps setting it to and e.company_id = 178 could provide a more efficient query as well.  Just a thought.

Comment: company_id is generating dyanamic, It can be one or more than one.

Comment: @rawat0157 So this entire statement is **dynamic SQL**?

Comment: yes @user2338816, this entire statement made by many conditions on java level